# Azure Management API: HTTP Post StatusCode: 403, ReasonPhrase: 'Forbidden'

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-management-api

I am receiving StatusCode: 403, ReasonPhrase: 'Forbidden' for an HTTP Post:

URL: `$"https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{appName}/functions/{functionName}/listkeys?api-version=2022-03-01";`

> StatusCode: 403, ReasonPhrase: 'Forbidden'

**Client:**

The following is my client code:

```
let tenantId = "<some_tenant_id>"
let clientId = "<some_client_id>"
let secret   = "<some_secret>"
let scope    = "<some_scope>"

let token = BearerToken.Create(tenantId, clientId, secret, scope).Result

let tokenRequestBody = Dictionary<string, string>() 
tokenRequestBody.Add("grant_type"   , "client_credentials")
tokenRequestBody.Add("client_id"    , clientId)
tokenRequestBody.Add("client_secret", secret)
tokenRequestBody.Add("scope"        , scope)

let content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(tokenRequestBody);

let httpKeysClient = new HttpClient();
httpKeysClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization <- new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
httpKeysClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

let subscriptionId    = "<some_scubscription_id>"
let resourceGroupName = "<some_resource_group_name>"
let appName           = "<some_function_app_name>"
let functionName      = "<some_function_name>"

let apiKeyUrl = $"https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{appName}/functions/{functionName}/listkeys?api-version=2022-03-01";

let response = httpKeysClient.PostAsync(apiKeyUrl, content).Result;

response.IsSuccessStatusCode |> should equal true // ** StatusCode: 403, ReasonPhrase: 'Forbidden' **
```

**Appendix:**

The code for creating an authorization token works:

```
public static class BearerToken
{
    public async static Task<string> Create(string tenantId, string clientId, string clientSecret, string scope)
    {
        var tokenRequestBody = new Dictionary<string, string> {

            { "grant_type"   , "client_credentials" },
            { "client_id"    , clientId },
            { "client_secret", clientSecret },
            { "scope"        , scope }
            };

        var url      = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token";
        var client   = new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = new Uri(url) };
        var content  = new FormUrlEncodedContent(tokenRequestBody);
        var response = await client.PostAsync("", content);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var tokenResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var valueFor      = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonSupport.AccessToken.Root>(tokenResponse);

            return valueFor.access_token;
        }

        throw new Exception(response.ReasonPhrase);
    }
}
```

Comment: The actual response body might contain more information about what is wrong (likely you dont have the correct permission to list keys, hence 403 instead of 401), try to deserialize it and log it.

Comment: Could you include what RBAC roles your service principal/application have?

Comment: @Sridevi - The role for my service principal is listed as 'Reader'

Comment: 'Reader' role is not sufficient to do POST operations. Try assigning 'Contributor' role to it.

Comment: @arynaq - I didn't see any additional details. However, the principal's role is set to reader.

Comment: @Sridevi - Under Active Directory | Roles and Administrators, it's not clear to me how to assign the principal a contributor role. Thoughts?

Comment: You need to assign 'Contributor' role under subscription, not under Azure Active directory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250814/discussion-between-sridevi-and-scott-nimrod).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment via Postman and got below results***

I have one service principal having **`Reader`** role under my subscription like below:

[image]

Now I generated **access token** using client credentials flow with below parameters:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token

grant_type:client_credentials
client_id: <appID>
client_secret: <secret_value>
scope: https://management.azure.com/.default
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used the above token to list keys, I got **`403 Forbidden`** error like below:

```http
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subID>/resourceGroups/Sri/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/<name>/functions/<functionname>/listkeys?api-version=2022-03-01
Authorization: Bearer <token>
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **resolve** the error, I assigned **`Contributor`** role to that service principal like below:

*Go to Azure Portal -> Subscriptions -> Your Subscription -> Access control (IAM) -> Add role assignment*

[image]

After assigning that role, I generated **access token** again and got the **results** successfully when I used that in below query:

```http
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subID>/resourceGroups/Sri/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/<name>/functions/<functionname>/listkeys?api-version=2022-03-01
Authorization: Bearer <token>
```

**Response:**

[image]

In your case, make sure to assign **`Contributor`** role to your service principal that resolves the issue.

Comment: Not sure if there's a similar approach to this question as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75190389/unable-to-access-a-pulumi-created-azure-storage-table-access-forbidden-403