# Unable to access a Pulumi Created Azure Storage Table - Access Forbidden (403)

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage, pulumi

I am receiving an Access Forbidden message when I attempt to access an Azure storage table that I created in Pulumi.

I have tried accessing the storage table in the Azure portal and in Azure Storage Explorer.

> {"odata.error":{"code":"AuthenticationFailed","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.\nRequestId:XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX\nTime:2023-01-20T23:21:57.8113163Z"}}}

[image]

The following code does not resolve the access forbidden issue:

```
var sas = Pulumi.Azure.Storage.GetAccountSAS.Invoke(new()
{
    ConnectionString = storageAccount.PrimaryConnectionString,
    HttpsOnly = true,
    SignedVersion = "2017-07-29",
    ResourceTypes = new Pulumi.Azure.Storage.Inputs.GetAccountSASResourceTypesInputArgs
    {
        Service   = true,
        Container = true,
        Object    = false,
    },
    Services = new Pulumi.Azure.Storage.Inputs.GetAccountSASServicesInputArgs
    {
        Blob  = true,
        Queue = true,
        Table = true,
        File  = true,
    },
    Start  = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssK"),
    Expiry = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssK"),
    Permissions = new Pulumi.Azure.Storage.Inputs.GetAccountSASPermissionsInputArgs
    {
        Read    = true,
        Write   = true,
        Delete  = false,
        List    = true,
        Add     = true,
        Create  = true,
        Update  = true,
        Process = true,
        Tag     = true,
        Filter  = true
    },
});
```

Update:
I'm researching how to use an [Account Access Key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/authorize-data-operations-portal#use-the-account-access-key).

**Access Control:**

The following is my access control for the storage account that harbors the storage table:

[image]

Comment: What RBAC role you currently have on storage account?

Comment: Contributor and reader.

Comment: Are you getting error for only tables or blob containers too from Portal?

Comment: I'm getting an error for just the table. Attaching screenshot

Comment: Please try by assigning [`Storage Table Data Contributor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#storage-table-data-contributor) role to your Service Principal.

Comment: @GauravMantri That resolved my access issue. Feel free to post this as the answer if you'd like. I think I will need to post a second question on how to assign this role programmatically (without using the Azure portal).

Comment: @Sridevi - Here's a separate question if you're available to help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75204048/unable-to-programmatically-add-update-azure-function-key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I agree with *@Gaurav Mantri*, you need to assign **Storage Table Data Contributor** role to your Service Principal.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got same error like below:***

[image]

To resolve the error, you need to assign **Storage Table Data
Contributor** role to your service principal as below:

[image]

After assigning **Storage Table Data Contributor** role to my account, I'm able to access the tables successfully like below:

[image]

To assign this role **programmatically** (without using the Azure portal), you can make use of below commands:

#### PowerShell:

```
Connect-AzAccount
New-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId  <sp_objectID> -RoleDefinitionName "Storage Table Data Contributor" -Scope "/subscriptions/<subscriptionID>/resourceGroups/<rgname>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<account_name>"
```

**Response:**

[image]

#### CLI:

```bash
az login
az role assignment create --assignee <sp_objectID> --role "Storage Table Data Contributor" --scope "/subscriptions/<subscriptionID>/resourceGroups/<rgname>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<account_name>"
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked Portal, role is assigned to **service principal** successfully under storage account like below:

[image]