# Unable to programmatically add/update Azure Function Key

Tags: azure, azure-functions

When attempting to programmatically add/update a function key, I receive the following error:

> StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized'

**Code:**

Executing the following code results in the error described above.

```
static void FunctionKey(string resourceGroupName, string functionAppName, string functionName, NameValuePair kv)
{
    var resource = $"subscriptions/{SubscriptionId.Value}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{functionAppName}/functions/{functionName}/keys/{kv.Name}?api-version=2022-03-01";
    var httpClient = new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://management.azure.com/") };
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", AuthToken.Value);
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    var json = @"{
                  ""Properties"": {
                    ""Name"": ""ApiKey"",
                    ""Value"": ""some_value""
                  }
                }";

    using (var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
    {
        var response = httpClient.PostAsync(resource, content).Result;

        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            throw new Exception($"Error: Failed to register function key for {functionName}");
    }
}
```

**Research:**

I was successful when performing this task in the the documentation [emulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/web-apps/create-or-update-function-secret?tryIt=true&source=docs#code-try-0).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this the exact code? The 404 hints on an incorrect url, and I can see you might have forgotten to replace the values between {xxxx} in the url

Comment: I compared the URL in my automated test with the URL in the documentation emulator. They are identical.

Comment: @Mocas - You were right. My test setup was executing the logic before my actual test would execute. This changed the state of things. Now I'm battling a bad request response that I can hopefully resolve.

Comment: I now get a 401 unauthorized. It's probably because my bearer token is empty.

Comment: Update: I fixed the unauthorized and back to 'Not found'. I checked the URL that succeeded with the one that failed and they are still identical.

Comment: Can you try hardcoding the url with the actual values instead of parameterizing it just for once to confirm?

Comment: Also, just pass the full address to the PostAsync method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251331/discussion-between-scott-nimrod-and-mocas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment via Postman and got below results:***

When I ran the below query without including bearer token, I got **same error** with `401 Unauthorized` like below:

```json
PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subID>/resourceGroups/<rgname>/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/<funcappname>/functions/<funcname>/keys/<keyname>?api-version=2022-03-01
{
    "Properties": 
        {
            "Name": "keyname",
            "Value": "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
        }
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

After passing the token, I'm able to create **function key** successfully like below:

[image]

When I checked the same portal, **`srikey`** appeared under function keys like below:

[image]

> In your case, you are using `httpClient.PostAsync` which means
> **POST** method.

When I used **POST** method for below query, I too got **`404 Not found`** error like below:

```json
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subID>/resourceGroups/<rgname>/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/<funcappname>/functions/<funcname>/keys/<keyname>?api-version=2022-03-01
{
    "Properties": 
        {
            "Name": "keyname",
            "Value": "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
        }
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **resolve** the error, make sure to use **PUT** method by changing  `httpClient.PostAsync` method to `httpClient.PutAsync` method.

**Reference:**
[HttpClient.PutAsync Method (System.Net.Http) | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.putasync?view=net-7.0)

Comment: I have a similar question if you're available: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75212448/http-post-to-azure-function-using-bearer-token-and-function-key-still-returns-un