# Mobile app performing an HTTP Post to Azure Function using Bearer Token and Function Key returns Unauthorized

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-functions, pulumi-azure

I'm using a mobile app and am receiving an Unauthorized response when attempting to post to an Azure Function and providing a function key.

**Error:**

```
StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized'
```

**Code:**

let postToAsync (baseAddress:string) (resource:string) (payload:Object) =

```
async {

    let tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan(0,0,30));
    let token = tokenSource.Token;
    
    try
        let tokens      = resource.Split("?code=")
        let functionKey = tokens.[1]

        use client = httpClient baseAddress
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-functions-key", functionKey)
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"))

        let  json     = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload)
        let  content  = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
        let! response = client.PostAsync(resource.Replace($"?code={functionKey}",""), content, token) |> Async.AwaitTask

        Debug.WriteLine $"\n\n{baseAddress}{resource}\nSuccess: {response.IsSuccessStatusCode}\n\n" 

        return response

    with ex -> ...
} |> Async.StartAsTask
```

**Note:**

My Azure Function's *AuthorizationLevel* is set to *Function*.

I can call the function successfully when I publish it manually from Visual Studio.
However, when I deploy the function using *Pulumi*, I receive an `Unauthorized` response. I believe this is because Pulumi constrains me to add access policies for each Function App.

**Versioning:**

```
<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
<AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
```

[image]

**oauth2/v2.0:**

I think the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55273120/4) provides a clue to why I'm observing the issue. However, I still don't know how to resolve it.

**Connectivity**

I launched Log Stream and observed that the URL is correct:

[image]

**Access Control:**

Please note that the difference between the Function App that I created without using Pulumi, which lets me post successfully, versus the Function App that was generated using Pulumi, is an Access Policy per Function App with Pulumi.

```
public static class AccessPolicies
{
    public static void Build(string policyName, string functionName, Dictionary<string, CustomResource> registry)
    {
        var resourceGroup = registry[nameof(ResourceGroup)] as ResourceGroup;
        var keyVault      = registry[nameof(KeyVault)]      as KeyVault;
        var functionApp   = registry[functionName]   as FunctionApp;

        var result = new AccessPolicy(policyName, new AccessPolicyArgs {

            KeyVaultId = keyVault.Id,
            TenantId   = TenantId.Value,
            ObjectId   = functionApp.Identity.Apply(v => v.PrincipalId ?? "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111"),
            KeyPermissions    = new[] { "Get", },
            SecretPermissions = new[] { "Get", }, 
        });

        registry.Add($"{policyName}-{functionName}", result);
    }
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: Could you include how you generated the **bearer** token with what scope? Have you added any **[identity provider](https://i.imgur.com/J19dqb8.png)** to your function app?

Comment: @Sridevi - I updated my post to include the bearer token implementation. Please note that this is the same implementation that I use for requests to Azure to update Azure Function keys. I don't think I added an Identity Provider to my function app.

Comment: I think you are using `https://management.azure.com/.default` as scope. Am I right?

Comment: Yes for the bearer token.

Comment: @Sridevi - I updated my post with Log Stream that shows confirmation on confirmed routing to function.

Comment: Setting the function's AuthorizationLevel to anonymous is a workaround.

Comment: Do you have a storage account attached to your function app? Also, do you see keys in the portal blade or when trying to run from the portal?

Answer (score 2):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment via Postman and got below results:***

I have one function app with http function named **`srifunction`** like below:

[image]

I generated one bearer token with **same scope** as you like below:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id: <appID>
client_secret: <secret_value>
scope: https://management.azure.com/.default
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used the above token to call function, I got **`401 Unauthorized`** error **same** as you like below:

```http
POST https://<funcappName>.azurewebsites.net/api/<function_name>
Authorization: Bearer <token>
```

[image]

If you pass  **function key** in token value, you will still get **`401 Unauthorized`** error like below:

```http
POST https://<funcappName>.azurewebsites.net/api/<function_name>
Authorization: Bearer <function key>
```

[image]

> To call function using **function key**, you need to include key value
> in **`x-functions-key`** **header** instead of Bearer token.

When I included the above **header**, I am able to call the function successfully like below:

```http
POST https://<funcappName>.azurewebsites.net/api/<function_name>
x-functions-key: <function key>
```

[image]

Comment: I'm getting a 404 'Not found'. I verified that the URL in Azure poral is identical to URL in my program. Here's the example URL: https://myFunctionApp.azurewebsites.net/api/ServiceKeysFn?code=some_key

Comment: Don't include **code** in the URL. Your URL should be like this `https://myfunctionapp.azurewebsites.net/api/ServiceKeysFn`

Comment: I removed the function key suffix from the URL but still receive the same error. I removed the key via the following: client.PostAsync(resource.Replace($"?code={functionKey}","")

Please note that Pulumi requires me to create Access Policies for each Function App. I updated my post to reflect the Access Control page for the Function App.

Comment: Instead of adding **x-functions-key** header in Authorization, can you try like this `client.defaultrequestheaders.Add("x-functions-key", "functionkeyvalue")`

Comment: I updated my post to reflect the example provided. Unfortunately, I get the same 'Not found' error. The URL still matches the 'Get Url' value in Azure. Would access policies that I depicted in my post impact this?

Comment: Not sure what might be the problem but ideally including `x-functions-key` header should give you results while calling a function with the function key. Maybe there are additional changes required on the Pulumi side as access policies are added.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251366/discussion-between-sridevi-and-scott-nimrod).